Scala 2.13 migration from 2.12 bring Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators
While I am trying to migrate scala project from 2.12 to 2.13 , I am getting the below error with following stracktrace
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$ivyBaseSettings$71(Defaults.scala:3206)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] (update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators

I have defined the dependency as
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2" .

I also have tried with
"org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-parser-combinators_2.13" % "1.1.2"

to force sbt to download the correct dependency but it didn't work for me either.
Can someone please help ?
I expect the repositories to be downloaded at least with 2.13 scala version

Maybe something in the runtime is forcing that other version? Did you cleaned and reloaded your workspace?

I am trying from console or terminal and the command I am using is "sbt clean compile". I believe,this should be enough.

Yeah, that should be enough. So it seems one of your dependencies is forcing the 2.12 one. You may try to use evicted and sbt-dependency-graph to inspect which is the faulty one. - Additionally, if you can create a small and public repo that reproduces the issue we may take a look.

Okay, thanks. Is there any example of using evicted or sbt-dependency-graph? I am trying with sbt show update but still getting the same issue. I am using sbt 1.6.2 and the following in plugins. When I increased the sbt from 1.6.2 to 1.10.0 ,it complains too.
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.2")
addSbtPlugin("de.heikoseeberger" % "sbt-header" % "5.6.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "1.0.0") // used to extract software version information
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.8.0")

evicted is a command available in sbt: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Eviction+warning - sbt-dependencty-graph was an external plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph but since 1.4.0 it is part of sbt as well, althouhg you may need to enable it using addDependencyTreePlugin in your project/plugins.sbt file. Then the docs of the Github repo should still work.
